# Selecting direct AND first child in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have an html setup like this:

```
<div class = "myClass">

     <div>
         <a>Content</a>
         <p><a>Content</a></p>  
     </div>


     <p><a>Content to CHANGE!</a></p>
     <p>Content</p>

</div>
```

I simply want to add 10px `margin-top` to the one labeled "Content to Change".  This `<p>` is a direct child of `class="myClass"` I beleive and it's the FIRST one that is a `<p>`;

however this CSS style isn't working:

```
.myClass p:nth-child(1) {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

OR

```
.myClass > p:nth-child(1) {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Anyone see why?

Comment: I think first child means first child, not first child of a particular tag name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `p` is not the first child of `.myClass`.  The `<div>` is.  Use:

```
.myClass p:first-of-type
```

You may also want to use

```
.myClass > p:first-of-type
```

to select the child explicitly.

Comment: Just as additional info, `:first-of-type` is all decent browser compatible and IE9+ - http://caniuse.com/#search=first-of-type For older IE you can use conditional comment and use jQuery for that. Css would be `.myClass p:first-of-type, .myClass p.firstOfType` and the jQ `$('.myClass').find('> p').eq(0).addClass('firstOfType')`

Comment: Only the second one, `.myClass > p:first-of-type`, does the trick. The first one, `.myClass p:first-of-type`, also selects the `p` inside the inner `div`. Both demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/HDkBS/

Comment: Hey that did it thanks!  Bonus:  What if I wanted to try `second-of-type` - is that a thing?  Edit:  Or is that what `nth-of-type` is?

Comment: @KickingLettuce no, only `:first-of-type` and `:last-of-type`, but there is `:nth-of-type`